# Изменение расширения

Tags: windows, windows-7

у меня есть много файлов в одной папке с типом файла: файл, расширения нет, как можно поменять им расширение?

Answer (score 2):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path ./ | Foreach-Object { Rename-Item -Path "$($_.FullName)" -NewName "$($_.FullName).ext" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью TotalCommander’а (https://www.ghisler.com/download.htm) производить групповое переименование файлов (как наименований, так и расширений)